# How to test if n / 2 * 3 + n % 2 * 2 will overflow?

Tags: c, overflow

How can I rewrite this test so that the test itself won't overflow? Can I use the fact that `(size_t) -1` is odd (power of 2 minus 1)?

```
size_t size;
...
if ((size * 3U + 1U) / 2U > (size_t) -1) {
    /* out of address space */
}
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, my question title was wrong. I don't want to check if `(n * 3 + 1) / 2` will overflow, but if `n / 2 * 3 + n % 2 * 2` will. I changed the title. Thanks for your correct replies to a bad question.

Comment: What is the type of `size`?

Comment: Can you use type bigger than type of `size`?

Comment: If `(n * 3 + 1) / 2` overflows, then so does `n * 3 + 1`. So you can just check for `n > (SIZE_MAX - 1) / 3`.

Comment: @pburk It's `size_t`. Edited.

Comment: If the overflow is your only worry, you can divide by 2 first, then multiply by 3. For example, you can use: (n / 2) * 3 + (n % 2) * 2;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for this precise formula, the reasoning behind it won't work for the general case, but for the given one, and many others, it does.

Overflow happens precisely when `size*3 + 1` is not representable, unsigned integer divisions can never overflow. So, your condition should be `size*3 + 1 > max_value`. Here, max_value is the unsigned value with all bits set, which you generated with `(size_t)-1`.

The `+1` can simply moved to the right side without invoking overflow since max_value is definitely greater than 1, so we arrive at `size*3 > max_value - 1`. Likewise, `*3` can be moved without invoking overflow. So what you need to check is `size > (max_value - 1)/3`.

---

Please note that, contrary to what I said originally (mea culpa), `size > max_value/3` does not work because max_value *is* a multiple of 3 when the integer type is unsigned (the condition is that there is an even number of bits available for positive numbers). So, the when size is `0x5555`, we get `3*size = 0xffff` and `3*size + 1 = 0x0000`. Sorry for mixing that up.

Comment: _Signed_ integer division _can_ overflow (e.g. `INT_MIN / -1`), but that's obviously irrelevant here.

Comment: Also, why can't `max_value` be a multiple of 3?  In fact, since `size_t` must contain an even number of bits, `max_value` _must_ be a multiple of 3.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen Nitpick: `size_t` need not have an even number of bits, but otherwise I agree with you.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen I'm very sorry, I mixed `2^n` up with `2^n-1`, so my reasoning about indivisibility with 3 was plain wrong. Since I could not delete the answer anymore, I have completely reworked the second part. Hope it's correct now. Thanks also for pointing out that `INT_MIN/-1` does overflow; even though it's not relevant here, and the only case in which overflow can occur, it's worth being precise, so I changed my assertion about integer division to _unsigned_ integer division.